# Heroku postgres node connection timeout

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, node-postgres, heroku-ssl, heroku-nodejs

I'm trying to connect to a Postgres database from my Heroku node app, which works when running locally, both through node and by running the `heroku local web` command, but when running it on Heroku, it times out while waiting for `pool.connect`

I'm running the following code snippet through the Heroku console (I've also tried using this code in my app directly, but this is more efficient than redeploying each time):

```
node -e "
    const { Pool } = require('pg');

    const pool = new Pool({
    connectionTimeoutMillis: 15000,
      connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL + '?sslmode=require',
      ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: true
      }
    });

    console.log('pool created');
    (async() => {

     try {
        console.log('connecting');
        const client = await pool.connect(); // this never resolves
        console.log('querying');
        const { rows } = await client.query('SELECT * FROM test_table LIMIT 1;');
        console.log('query success', rows);
        client.release()
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('query error', error);
      }
    })()
"
```

Things I've tried so far:

- Using the pg `Client`instead of `Pool`
- Using `ssl: true` instead of `ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: true }`
- Using `client.query` without using `pool.connect`
- Increased and omitted `connectionTimeoutMillis` (it resolves quickly when running locally since I'm querying a database that has just one row)
- I've also tried using callbacks and promises instead of async / await
- I've tried setting the connectionString both with the `?sslmode=require` parameter and without it

  - I have tried using pg versions `^7.4.1` and `^7.18.2` so far

My assumption is that there is something I'm missing with either the Heroku setup or SSL, any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: If changing to v7 of `node-postgres` fixes it for you, then the problem is due to the v8 changes, [as listed in the changelog](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#pg800).

Comment: I have tried using pg versions `^7.4.1` and `^7.18.2` so far, will update the description